# bash variable changes in loop with ffmpeg

Tags: bash, loops, ffmpeg

I wrote a skript to quickly create short preview clips from vides I recorded on timestamps that I found worth checking out later for cutting. 
My file with the timestamps is written like this

```
FILE_NAME1#MM:SS MM:SS
FILE_NAME2#MM:SS MM:SS MM:SS MM:SS
```

example:

```
MAH01728#02:47 03:34 03:44 05:00 06:08 06:55
```

The script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while read f
 do

 file=$(echo $f | cut -d"#" -f1)
 filename=${file}".MP4"
 timestamps=$(echo $f | cut -d"#" -f2)

for time in $timestamps 
 do 
  ffmpeg -ss 00:${time}.0 -i "orig/${filename}" -c copy -t 10 "preview/${file}_${time}.MP4"
 done
done < $1
```

The script gets half of the previews that I want and on the other the filename is messed up and ffmpeg complains that the file is not found:

```
orig/714.MP4: No such file or directory
orig/00:58 01:25.MP4: No such file or directory
```

So I modified the script for trouble shooting and just put an echo in front of the ffmpeg command - now all file names are correct. What am I missing?

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:47.0 -i orig/MAH01714.MP4 -c copy -t 10 preview/MAH01714_01:47.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 00:02:00.0 -i orig/MAH01713.MP4 -c copy -t 10 preview/MAH01713_02:00.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:58.0 -i orig/MAH01712.MP4 -c copy -t 10 preview/MAH01712_00:58.MP4
ffmpeg -ss 00:01:25.0 -i orig/MAH01712.MP4 -c copy -t 10 preview/MAH01712_01:25.MP4
```

Comment: This might help: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`ffmpeg` reads from standard input, consuming data from `$1` that was intended for the `read` command at the top of the loop. Redirect its standard input from `/dev/null`:

```
while IFS="#" read file timestamps; do
  filename="$file.MP4"
  for time in $timestamps; do
    ffmpeg -ss 00:${time}.0 -i "orig/${filename}" \
           -c copy -t 10 "preview/${file}_${time}.MP4" < /dev/null
  done
done < "$1"
```

`echo` does *not* read from standard input, which is why your modification made it appear to be working correctly.

Comment: Alternatively, use the `-nostdin` option in `ffmpeg`.

Comment: That is great. I did not know you could specify the IFS in the while loop and also asign multiple variables. Much leaner. This worked for me.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard 
Thank you tried this as well and with this line it works:
    ffmpeg -nostdin -ss 00:${time}.0 -i "orig/${filename}" \
           -c copy -t 10 "preview2/${file}_${time}.MP4"

Comment: ffmpeg is the most bizarre, most idiosyncratic piece of software I've ever seen. Reading from stdin is the sneakiest way to make scripts fail and very hard to troubleshoot when they do so. But I would not expect the ffmpeg devs to understand why it's incredibly wrong to do this. Thanks for the solution BTW.

Comment: It would be good to explain why does it read from stdin, and where is the WONTFIXED bug report for this :-)